# ImportError : cannot import name generic

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have installed Django 1.10. I need to import the loafing but not able to import it. I am trying to connect my django app with elasticsearch using Haystack and wanted to build index. The code I want to run is

> python manage.py rebuild_index

The error I get is:

```
base ---dir
/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/ad-tracking-django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catalog/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
ImportError: cannot import name generic
```

The main error is:

> ImportError: cannot import name generic

Comment: loading class is not available in django 1.10 (removed in 1.9)

Comment: what alternative should I use?

Comment: apps is the equivalent of loading in 1.9+  `django.apps`

Comment: is it 'app' or 'apps'?

Comment: `django.apps` not app

Comment: `from django.db.models import apps` is this ok?

Comment: see the answer. Comments are kind of uneasy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loading` class has been removed in django 1.9 so that's why you are getting the error. Instead you can use `apps` class.

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
```

EDIT: 
`generic` class is also removed in [v1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#features-removed-in-1-9) and functionality has been moved to models class and fields class.

```
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name generic` this error is shown when I change the import. Is this too changed in Django 1.10?

Comment: post the full traceback of this error to the question

Comment: I will create a new question based on the generic error

Comment: The above solves the loading class problem although can not import name generic is the error because of contenttype class in django. Create another question or edit this one. I can help once you post the import statement and traceback

Comment: I can only ask new questions every 90 mins so I edited the question

Comment: `yield apps.cache.get_model(*model_str.split('.'))
AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'cache'`                              
gives this error @Arpit

Comment: you should post another question for this else it will divert too much from its original question.

Comment: then should we chat about that error? I cannot post another question for 78 mins. And I have to solve this problem immediately. I would have tried myself but I have not understood the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150519/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-manish-ojha).

Comment: Why is the chat page not opening?

Comment: don't know opening on my pc. Wait for some time around 1 hour to create another question

Comment: I will inform you when I post the question by posting something here. Please do reply

Comment: The chat worked on my pc. Please try with your computer once